# How do you allow a specific IP Address to bypass your firewall. OS X

Tags: macos, networking, firewall, bypass

Well, my young cousin really likes minecraft. He comes over and spends time with me every now and then. When he does, we usually play minecraft, as it is one of the few games I actually like. Anyway, he wanted his friend to play on the world we created. I don't want him on the global multiplayer server, but a custom one I am fine with.

I set up the minecraft server, and it should work, expect for one little thing. The firewall.

I have a few computers in my network, I have an AT&T 2Wire box. The computer I am running the server on is my Mac. Now, I could just disable the firewall for the few hours we play, but I really would prefer to not do that. Instead, is it possible for me to take the IP Address of his friend's computer, and allow that address to bypass my firewall?

If you have another idea, feel free to share it.

Comment: (1) Are you able to setup the port forwarding 2Wire? (2) Regarding firewall, are you referring to the one on the Mac? If so, we can work on pf.conf bypass rules for the Mac.

Comment: No, not the firewall on the Mac, on the router. You know, on gateway.2wire.net. I might be able to set up port forwarding. However, I did try something, I just need to check if it works. I added a new user-defined application, named it Minecraft, and put in the port I want. Then, I will change the security measure from most secure, to specific application. If I allow minecraft, then they should be able to access the port... Hopefully.

Comment: Correct, all you need is port forwarding to your Mac. Once it is setup correctly, whenever your cousin visit you, you enable the rules. When they leave, you can disable it.

Comment: Right, I'll try that out and see if it works.